# iterating through multiset of structs

Tags: c++, stl, set

I'm not getting the syntax right. Lets say I have this...

```
#include <set>
...    
struct foo{
    int bar;
    string test;
};

struct comp{
    inline bool operator()(const foo& left,const foo& right){
        return left.bar < right.bar;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::multiset<foo,comp> fooset;
    std::multiset<foo,comp>::iterator it;

    ...//insert into fooset

    for (it = fooset.begin(); it != fooset.end(); it++){
        //how do i access int bar and string test of each element?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do i access int bar and string test of each element inside the for loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good mnemonic rule that an iterator is a safe C++ abstraction for pointer.

So basically you access the elements through dereferencing syntax:

```
(*it).bar = 0;
it->test = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (it = fooset.begin(); it != fooset.end(); it++)
{
      foo const & f = *it; //const is needed if it is C++11
      //use f, e.g
      std:: cout << f.bar <<", " << f.test << std::endl;
}
```

In C++11, you could do this instead:

```
for(foo const & f : fooset)
{
      //use f, e.g
      std:: cout << f.bar <<", " << f.test << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `const` is needed in any case.

Comment: @n.m.: C++03 doesn't require you to do that, I think.

Comment: It does. C++ requires elements to be ordered w.r.t. some ordering relation, because the implementation typically uses some kind of binary search tree internally. If you change the elements such their relative order changes, the tree will become invalid. For the same reason keys in `std::map` are constant.

Comment: @n.m.: That is the rationale why C++11 requires `const`, but C++03 apparently doesn't, as far as I know, which means, if I'm correct, is a design bug.

Comment: My bad. I was pretty sure it's in TR1, as the defect report dates back to 1998. G++ implements constness anyway since at least 2002.