# How to check a multiset if a certain struct member exists, other than with a for loop?

Tags: c++, if-statement, struct, multiset

I am altering a [relaxed A* program](https://web.archive.org/web/20180611021016/https://github.com/coins-lab/relaxed_astar) to use A* instead. As part of the [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) there is the check:

```
if neighbor not in openSet
   openSet.add(neighbor)
```

The openSet is a:

```
multiset<cells> OPL;
```

With cells being:

```
struct cells {
    int currentCell;
    float fCost;
};
```

So, I would like to add this check whether the neighbor already exists in the openSet to my code. However, a struct in a multiset is something I've not worked with before.
The solution I've arrived at for now was inspired by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826588/iterating-through-multiset-of-structs) and works as such:

```
for (std::multiset<cells>::iterator it = OPL.begin(); it != OPL.end(); it++)
{
      cells const & f = *it;
      if(f.currentCell==neighborCell){
          return false;
      }
}
return true;
```

However, this seems inefficient. Originally I tried to see if I could use OPL.find() or something instead of having to run through the entire openSet each time, but I couldn't get it to work.

So I've come here to see whether some smart people have a better solution I can use and learn from ^^?

Comment: You could use `find()`?

Comment: Since the object you are finding is not the same as the value type of the container it seems like a case for a transparent comparator (only usable from C++20 however).

Comment: Link for [transparent comparators](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/06/09/search-set-another-type-key/), this article mentions C++14 but this technique only becomes available for unordered_multiset from C++20.

Answer (score 1):

`openSet` should be a `multimap` from `currentCell` to `fCost`.  Then your problem is easy.

What more, I'm not sure what `multi` earns you -- you usually don't care about sub-optimal paths when doing A*.

...

You can also use a `cells` with -INF and +INF in the `fCost` field and do a lower/upper bound on them (assuming that the `fCost` must be finite), forming a range of entries that match your `currentCell`.

Possibly easier is a lower bound, followed by a linear search until you are at the end of the list or find a `currentCell` that matches/doesn't match what you want.

```
cells tmp = neighborCell;
tmp.fCost = -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
auto it = OPL.lower_bound(tmp);
if (it == OPL.end()) return false;
return it->currentCell == tmp.currentCell;
```

In addition, in later versions of C++ you can have what is known as a "transparent comparator".  This one can intelligently know about "I just want the current cell", and do an `equal_range` directly.